# SQL Query Performance with count

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables, `COMPANY` and `EMPLOYEE`.

`COMPANY_ID` is the primary key of the `COMPANY` table and foreign key for `EMPLOYEE` table. The `COMPANY_ID` is a 10 digit number. We are generate a 3 number combination and query the database.

The `select` statement has regex to bulk load the company based on `COMPANY_ID`. The query is executed multiple times with different patterns

i.e.

```
regexp_like(COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)') .
```

Existing query looks something like this -

```
select * 
from COMPANY company
where regexp_like(company.COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)')
```

The new requirement is to retrieve the company information along with the employee count. For example if a company has 10 employees, then the query should return all the columns of the `COMPANY` table, along with employee count i.e. 10

This is the select statement that I came up with -

```
select 
    nvl(count_table.cont_count, 0), company.* 
from 
    COMPANY company,
    (select company.COMPANY_ID, count(company.COMPANY_ID) as cont_count 
     from COMPANY company, EMPLOYEE employee
     where regexp_like(company.COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)') 
       and company.CONTACT_ID = employee.CONTACT_ID     
     group by (company.COMPANY_ID)) count_table
 where 
     regexp_like(company.COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)') 
     and count_table.COMPANY_ID(+)= company.COMPANY_ID
```

Above query works, but it takes double the time compared to the previous statement. Is there a better way to retrieve the employee count?

Note: Oracle database is in use.

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: So if this is an Oracle platform, why are you listing Mysql and sql-server tags?  You need to run an explain plan and see what the db is doing with the query.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute that expensive REGEXP_LIKE twice:

```
 select nvl(count_table.cont_count,0),company.* 
 from COMPANY company 
 ,( select   employee.COMPANY_ID, count(employee.COMPANY_ID) as cont_count
    from     EMPLOYEE employee
     group by (employee.COMPANY_ID)
  ) count_table
  where regexp_like(company.COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)') 
  and count_table.COMPANY_ID(+)= company.COMPANY_ID
```

Or you could use a scalar subquery:

```
select company.* 
,      (select count(*)
        from   employee e
        where  e.company_id = c.company_id
       )
from COMPANY c 
where regexp_like(c.COMPANY_ID, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)')
```

And personally I would ditch the slow REGEXP_LIKE for something like:

```
where substr(c.company_id,1,3) between '000' and '009'
```

Answer (score 1):

The derived table does not add value, thus I would get rid of it and use a scalar query (because I do not know all of your columns in the company table to properly do a group by):

```
select c.*,
  nvl(
  (select count(1)
  from employee emp
  where emp.company_id = c.company_id
  ),0) employee_count
from company c
where regexp_like(c.company_id, '^(000|001|002|003|004|005|006|007|008|009)')
```

Also, if performance is still an issue, I would consider modifying your where statement to not use a regexp.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Addendum
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I see that the question explicitly identifies that the employee table has company_id as a foreign key.  Since this is clarified, I am removing this statement:

> The data model for these  tables is not intuitive (would you not have
>   company_id as a foreign key in the employees table?).